# How to fix java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error here?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is to create a polygon object, which consists of an ArrayList of Point2D objects and then find the perimeter of it.

**Polygon Class**

```
public void addPoint(Point2D.Double p) {
    point.add((Point2D.Double) p);
}

public double perimeter() {
    double perimeter = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < point.size(); i++) {
        perimeter += point.get(i).distance(point.get(i + 1));
    }
    return perimeter;
}
```

**Main Class**

```
Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon();

Point2D.Double p1 = new Point2D.Double(10, 20);
Point2D.Double p2 = new Point2D.Double(20, 30);
Point2D.Double p3 = new Point2D.Double(10, 40);

polygon1.addPoint(p1);
polygon1.addPoint(p2);
polygon1.addPoint(p3);

System.out.println(polygon1.perimeter());
```

Comment: perimeter += point.get(i).distance(point.get(i + 1)); gives you the IndexOutOfBounds Exception. Please provide full code of Polygon Class  or atleast the the distance method. So we can think about a way to fix your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `i + 1` object, which may not exist in the list when You are iterating. For example, if you have only one element in the list the `for` loop will start at the 0, so you will have something like this for `i == 0` :

```
        perimeter += point.get(0).distance(point.get(0 + 1));
```

But You don't have the element with index 1 in the list so it will throw an exception.There are two ways of fixing this issue:

1) You can change the for loop to `for (int i = 0; i < point.size()-1; i++)`. And then increase the perimeter for the last point manually after the `for` loop.

2) You can leave the loop as it is but simply add the condition:

```
if(i == point.size()-1`) {
        perimeter += point.get(i).distance(point.get(0));
}
```

Comment: could also use the the conditinal `?: ` or even the modulo operator `%` like in `...get((i+1) % point.size())`

Comment: Thanks for the response and the solutions! I increased the perimeter manually after the for loop. It seemed more logical.

Answer (score 2):

`point.get(i + 1)` doesn't exist at the end of the loop

Use `int i = 0; i < point.size() - 1`

Comment: missing the segment from last point to first n the perimeter, but the answer is correct (avoid exception)